# How to get Total COUNT With group_concat() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get first 5 concatenated ids + total rows found. How can i achive this in mysql?

```
SELECT 
  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
  GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids ,
  COUNT(*) AS total_rows
FROM
  my_table 
LIMIT 0, 5 ;
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: You want to select one result row containing A) the total number of records in the table, and B) five arbitrarily chosen IDs from the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the number of rows within a subquery, then perform the aggregation over that:

```
select group_concat(x1.id) as ids, 
       (select count(*) from mytable) as total_rows
from
(
  select id
  from MyTable
  order by id
  limit 5
) x1
```